# how can i get answer for python list of comprehension

Tags: python

Is there anyone can help me to pass this session of python course. I tried but not working.
Given a word as input, output a list, containing only the letters of the word that are not vowels.

The vowels are a, e, o, u.

This is my code:

```
word=input()
word=list(word)

out=[l for l in word if not l in vowels]
print(out)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: What is not working currently? Does this produce an error or a wrong answer? Which exactly?

Comment: The vowels are a, e, o, u, **i, y**. You've got a grammar problem, not programming one.

Comment: missing vowels variable in list comprehension? If so, you can add as variable of strings (vowels = 'aeou')

Comment: `word` already "looks" like a list and casting it to a list with `word=list(word)` is redundant in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

hi u have not specfified what the vowels are. u have to specify it for the computer to intepret it. Here is the solution:

```
word=input()
word=list(word)
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"] # set of vowels
out = [l for l in word if l not in vowels] # list with only constants
print(out)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In the provided code, there is no vowels variable that is used in list comprehensions. Its not the list comprehension error. I guess its `NameError`  where name is not defined

```
word = input()
vowels = 'aeou'
word_list = list(word)

out = [l for l in word_list if l not in vowels]
print(out)
```

Output

```
test
['t', 's', 't']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Those codes will work the same. If OP's doesn't work, yours won't either.

Comment: I n the provided code, there is no `vowels` variable that is used in list comprehensions. Its not the list comprehension error. I guess its `NameError`  where name is not defined